# Customize radiobutton

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am trying to customize some radiobuttons. I want to customize the label in order to make is as a clickable button, as in this figure:
[image]

Moreover I introduced a change color of the new label botton when hover and another one when focus as in these figures:
[image]
[image]

Finally I would like to hide the typical circular button as this result:
[image]

I have two main problems:

1) if I hide the input button ( for example with `display:none`) I am no more able to choose the radiobutton I want.

2 ) I introduced the change color when radiobutton is checked with the property `focus-within` but this do not satisfy me enough. Indeed when I load the page and the button is checked by default, I didn't see any change in color, because I am not focused on it.

The code I used is the following:

```css
.form-control {
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out,box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    list-style: none;
}

.inline-item {
    display: inline-block;
}

.chip-container .chip-selection label {
    height: 28px;
    padding: 5px 10px 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #7d7d7d;
    border: #7d7d7d 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: none;
}

.chip-container .chip-selection label:hover {
    color: $footer_color;
    background-color: #D1F5FF;
    border: #1b8cab 1px solid;
}


.chip-container .chip-selection label:focus-within {
    color: white;
    background-color: #1b8cab;
    border: #1b8cab 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-short">

  <ul class="form-control chip-container">

     <li class="inline-item chip-selection"><label for="id_0">
     <input type="radio" name="input_th" value="false"  id="id_0" checked="">
        old checkbox</label>
      </li>

      <li class="inline-item chip-selection"><label for="id_1">
      <input type="radio" name="input_th" value="true"  id="id_1">
        new trial checkbox</label>
      </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

The main problem is that I can't change the html structure , and the input is child of the label.
It is also better for me to not use any javascript, I would like to know if there is some CSS trick to solve my problem

Thanks a lot to whom can help me
Andrea

Comment: I don't understand your first problem.

Comment: No, this is not possible using CSS alone, not with that HTML structure. `:focus-within` will not do the trick if you want to mark the label of a _checked_ checkbox - focus and checked state are two different things. Even if it works in the moment you click a checkbox, it will stop working as soon as the focus is switched to a different part of the page. You need an element sibling following the checkbox to achieve this using CSS alone.

Comment: Thanks, 04FS I'll look forward for another way to overcome the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Add `opacity` & `position`

```
.chip-container .chip-selection label input{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```css
.form-control {
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out,box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    list-style: none;
}

.inline-item {
    display: inline-block;
}

.chip-container .chip-selection label {
    height: 28px;
    padding: 5px 10px 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #7d7d7d;
    border: #7d7d7d 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: none;
}

.chip-container .chip-selection label:hover {
    color: $footer_color;
    background-color: #D1F5FF;
    border: #1b8cab 1px solid;
}


.chip-container .chip-selection label:focus-within {
    color: white;
    background-color: #1b8cab;
    border: #1b8cab 1px solid;
}
.chip-container .chip-selection label input{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-short">

  <ul class="form-control chip-container">

     <li class="inline-item chip-selection"><label for="id_0">
     <input type="radio" name="input_th" value="false"  id="id_0" checked="">
        old checkbox</label>
      </li>

      <li class="inline-item chip-selection"><label for="id_1">
      <input type="radio" name="input_th" value="true"  id="id_1">
        new trial checkbox</label>
      </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try THis

```css
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm"> 
<label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

Comment: I can't change html structure

Answer (score 0):

You may try by reducing the width of input..May this help you..

```
input {
    width: 0px;
}
```